# How to stop curly brace on new line when formatting the code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using VSCode and have installed `phpfmt` PHP formater extension. When I hit the format code option, the cruly braces of functions and classes are set to new line. I have practice of adding curly brace on the same line and I want the same to be done by the formater.

What I want is:

```
public function abc () {

}
```

What PHP formater does is:

```
public function abc ()
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me:

```
"phpfmt.psr2": false,
```

This option is enabled by default and and [as written in this standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

> Opening braces for methods MUST go on the next line

Answer (score -2):

```
"phpfmt.exclude": ["AllmanStyleBraces"]
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. Please explain how it is supposed to work and why it is supposed to help.